# The simplest way of printing a portion of a char[] in C

Tags: c, string-formatting

Let's say I have a `char* str = "0123456789"` and I want to cut the first and the last three letters and print just the middle, what is the simplest, and safest, way of doing it?

Now the trick: The portion to cut and the portion to print are of variable size, so I could have a very long char*, or a very small one.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `printf()`, and a special format string:

```
char *str = "0123456789";
printf("%.6s\n", str + 1);
```

The precision in the `%s` conversion specifier specifies the maximum number of characters to print.  You can use a variable to specify the precision at runtime as well:

```
int length = 6;
char *str = "0123456789";    
printf("%.*s\n", length, str + 1);
```

In this example, the * is used to indicate that the next argument (`length`) will contain the precision for the `%s` conversion, the corresponding argument must be an `int`.

Pointer arithmetic can be used to specify the starting position as I did above.

**[EDIT]**

One more point, if your string is shorter than your precision specifier, less characters will be printed, for example:

```
int length = 10;
char *str = "0123456789";
printf("%.*s\n", length, str + 5);
```

Will print "`56789`".  If you always want to print a certain number of characters, specify both a minimum field width and a precision:

```
printf("%10.10s\n", str + 5);
```

or

```
printf("%*.*s\n", length, length, str + 5);
```

which will print:

```
"     56789"
```

You can use the minus sign to left-justify the output in the field:

```
printf("%-10.10s\n", str + 5);
```

Finally, the minimum field width and the precision can be different, i.e.

```
printf("%8.5s\n", str);
```

will print at most 5 characters right-justified in an 8 character field.

Comment: That’s pretty cool. I only learned about the string truncation earlier today (I guess I’ve always just done my substringing with the actual strings instead of `printf`). Now why is that not possible with integers? Why can you not say for example `printf("%.2d", 123);` to print only `23` or `printf("%-.2d", 123);` to print only `12`? `:-|`

Answer (score 9):

Robert Gamble and Steve separately have most of the pieces.
Assembled into a whole:

```
void print_substring(const char *str, int skip, int tail)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    assert(skip >= 0);
    assert(tail >= 0 && tail < len);
    assert(len > skip + tail);
    printf("%.*s", len - skip - tail, str + skip);
}
```

Invocation for the example:

```
print_substring("0123456789", 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind modifying the data, you could just do some pointer arithmetic. This is assuming that str is a char pointer and not an array:

```
char string[] = "0123456789";
char *str = string;

str += 3; // "removes" the first 3 items
str[4] = '\0'; // sets the 5th item to NULL, effectively truncating the string

printf(str); // prints "3456"
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that the string is writable, then it is 'OK'.  But since it is not necessary to modify the string, it is better not to.

Comment: And you should save the old value before zapping it, and then reinstate it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean and simple substring function I dug up from my personal library that may be useful:

```
char *
substr(const char *src, size_t start, size_t len)
{
  char *dest = malloc(len+1);
  if (dest) {
    memcpy(dest, src+start, len);
    dest[len] = '\0';
  }
  return dest;
}
```

It's probably self-explanatory but it takes a string, a starting position (starting at zero), and a length and returns a substring of the original string or a null pointer if malloc fails.  The pointer returned can be `free`'d by the caller when the memory is no longer needed.  In the spirit of C, the function doesn't validate the starting position and length provided.

Answer (score -2):

I believe there is some magic you can do with printf that will only print a certain number of characters, but it's not commonly understood or used.  We tried to do it at a previous job and couldn't get it to work consistently.

What I would do is save off a character, null that character in the string, print it, then save it back.

Comment: See my printf example, I've used this method for a long time and it has always worked consistently for me.

Comment: The save-null-restore trick fails abysmally when the source string is a constant.  Don't do it.

Comment: Robert: are you sure this format (eg: %.*) works with *any* C compiler?

Comment: @botismarius: It will work with any C library that supports C89 or C99, it has been standard for 20 years, from the C89 spec:
"A field width or precision, or both, may be indicated by an
asterisk * instead of a digit string.  In this case, an int argument
supplies the field width or precision."

Comment: I'm glad I got modded down after I saw how simple the example was.  In our case, we had trouble getting the "use string length from the previous argument" feature to work consistently across all of the platforms we needed.  That's the best of my recollection.