# How to print only certain parts of a string?

Tags: c, string, printf

I have a  string `const char[15]` and I want to print it like this:

> Label-one: *characters [0,13)*
>   Label-two: *characters [13,  15)*

How can I print only certain parts of the string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256218/the-simplest-way-of-printing-a-portion-of-a-char-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
printf( "%.13s", labelOne );   // stops after thirteen characters.
printf( "%.3s", &labelOne[ 13 ] );  // prints three characters of the string that starts at offset 13
```

I'm noticing a possible fencepost error/inconsistency in your question or my answer, depending on your point of view. The correct answer for the second example may be:

```
printf( "%.3s", &labelOne[ 12 ] );
```

Comment: A small stylistic advice: `labelOne + 13` seems neater and more natural than `&labelOne[13]`.

Comment: @Blagovest -- Force of habit I suppose. I've gone back and forth on the issue, and to your point, your format is much more common today. When I started developing in C lo these many years, the &str[ offset ] format seemed to be more commonplace.

Answer (score 17):

```
printf("Label-one: %.*s", 13, str);
printf("Label-two: %.*s", 2, str + 13);
```

@Bob's answer is also acceptable if these lengths are constant, but in case the lengths are determined at runtime, this is the best approach since it parametrises them.