# How to print a string using printf without it printing the trailing newline

Tags: c, string, printf, null-terminated

I'm trying to print some strings using `printf()` but they are <del>null terminated</del> having trailing newline and that messes with the formating:

```
printf("The string \"%s\" was written onto the file \"%s\"", str, fname);
```

Say the string contains `"The Racing car."` and the file name is `"RandomText1.txt"`
This prints:

```
The string "The Racing car.
" was written onto the file "RandomText1.txt
"
```

However I want it to print in just one line:

```
The string "The Racing car." was written onto the file "RandomText1.txt"
```

I know I can modify the strings to get rid of the <del>null terminator</del> newline but I'd like a way, if possible, to achieve this output without modifying the strings.

Is it possible?

Comment: "null-terminator"? Don't you mean an included newline?

Comment: They're __not__ null-terminated, they have a beeline char at the end

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie to programming. I thought the \n was the null terminator

Comment: @ForceBru I think your words are _a little_ misleading, they __are__ null-terminated and having a `\n` before the null-termination, IMHO  :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, yes, you're certainly right. I meant, the null-termination wasn't the problem here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the null terminator. a *string* **must** be null-terminated.

You're facing issues with the trailing newline (`\n`) here. you have to *strip off* that newline before passing the string to `printf()`.

Easiest way [*requires modification of `str`*]: You can do this with [`strcspn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn). Pseudo code:

```
str[strcspn(str,"\n")] = 0;
```

> *if possible, to achieve this output without modifying the strings.*

Yes, possible, too. In that case, you need to use the length modifier with `printf()` to limit the length of the array to be printed, something like,

```
printf("%15s", str);  //counting the ending `.` in str as shown
```

but IMHO, this is not the best way, as, the length of the string has to be known and fixed, otherwise, it won't work.

A little flexible case,

```
printf("%.*s", n, str);
```

where, `n` has to be supplied and it needs to hold the length of the string to be printed, (without the newline)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie to programming. I thought the \n was the null terminator

Comment: @Tiagofer Nevermind, happens. BTW, you should check my updated answer. :-)

Comment: I had to go away for a while so I just had the oportunity to look at your updated answer now. It's awesome, thank you! :D

Answer (score 7):

As already pointed out, every string in C should be null-terminated (else - how could `printf` know where the string ends?)

You need to search the array for new-lines, presumably using [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/).

Try this:

```
  char* first_newline = strchr(str, '\n');
  if (first_newline)
      *first_newline = '\0';
```

It will terminate the string at the first instance of a newline.

Comment: @iharob right, but somehow it does not answer the question `without modifying the strings`, as requested by OP. but then again, it's accepted, so.. Peace :-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Take a look at this ;)

[How to print only certain parts of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841926/how-to-print-only-certain-parts-of-a-string)

You'll just have to print 'strings lenths - 1' characters

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you read data in array `str` using standard function `fgets` (or some other method) that includes in the string also the new line  character `'\n'` that coresponds to Enter key.

You shoud remove this character. This can be done the following way

```
size_t n = strlen( str );

if ( n && str[n-1] == '\n' ) str[n-1] = '\0';
```