# why i can't compare those arrays in files and that i read to create a login system?

Tags: c, string, newline, fgets

The `strcmp()` function is not working. The username I am reading from console doesn't match the one i Have in the file. So, the output is wrong id.
What is the solution?

```
  #include<stdio.h>       
  #include<stdlib.h>        
  #include<string.h>       
  int main()         
  {    
   FILE *pass;     
   char str[100],str2[100];     
   char id[100],pw[100];        
   pass=fopen("password.txt","r");         
   printf("ENTER USER NAME AND PASSWORD:\n");        
   printf("USERNAME: ");       
   gets(id);            
   printf("\nPASSWORD: ");         
   gets(pw);       
   while(fgets(str,100,pass)!=NULL);            
   {        
    fgets(str2,100,pass);      
    if(strcmp(id,str)==0)       
    {       
      if(strcmp(pw,str2)==0)         
      {       
        printf("ACCEPTED\n");            
      }       
      else       
      {        
        printf("wrong password");          
       }        
   }        
   else         
    {          
      printf("wrong id");           
    }           
    }    
    fclose(pass);    
   }
```

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917)

Comment: I suggest you read more about [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and learn how it's different from e.g. `gets`. Incidentally, if you use `fgets` to read input from `stdin` as well, then it would have worked.

Comment: i can't understand the \n thing and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917), use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) always.

That said, `fgets()`, reads and stores the trailing newline into the target buffer.

From `C11`, chapter 7.21.7.2

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a new-line character **(which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

You should get rid of that newline before making use of the scanned value. [Here's one way to have that accomplished](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30261047/2173917).

Comment: Or, if using `fgets` to read the input from `stdin`, do nothing. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude True, but I'd like to have my inputs _sanitized_ before I use them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the `fopen()` was successful before accessing the file that the program attempted to open.

`fopen()` returns `NULL` on error. So do something like

```
pass=fopen("password.txt","r");         
if( pass==NULL )
{
    perror("Unable to open input file.");       
}
else
{
    // Use the file 
}
```

And `gets()` is known to severe security concerns. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

It is advisable to use a `fgets()` instead with `stdin` as an argument. So instead of

```
gets(id);
```

try

```
if( fgets(id, sizeof(id), stdin)!=NULL )
{
    id[ strlen(id)-1 ] = '\0';
    // Use `id` 
}
```

The value returned by `fgets()` is also checked to see that `fgets()` was successful. It returns `NULL` on error.

It should be noted that `fgets()` would read in the trailing `\n` from stdin as well.

You may remove this extra `\n` with the help of a  function like `strlen()`. See a discussion on removing the extra newline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Use the same while reading into `pw` as well.

Assuming that your input file has the id in one line and the corresponding password in the line after that, you could do something like

```
char flag=0;
while(fgets(str, sizeof str, pass)!=NULL && fgets(str2, sizeof str2, pass)!=NULL)
{
    str[ strlen(str)-1 ] = '\0';
    str2[ strlen(str2)-1 ] = '\0';
    if( strcmp(str, id)==0 )
    {
        flag=1;
        if( strcmp(str2, pw)==0 )
        {
            printf("ACCEPTED\n");            
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("wrong password.");
        }
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==0) 
{
    printf("Wrong id.");    
}
```

Read two lines at once and check if both are successful before each iteration of the loop to ensure that proper values have been read.

You may want to break out of the loop once you find the password to be wrong.

You could also use a flag variable to see if the id that was input was valid and print the corresponding message at the end.