# Is there a function to align string with spaces or special character?

Tags: c, string, format

**EDIT: This is A duplicate.**

[Set variable text column width in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105890/set-variable-text-column-width-in-printf) & [The simplest way of printing a portion of a char[] in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256218/the-simplest-way-of-printing-a-portion-of-a-char-in-c)
Answered my question

I want to output a menu in C but I can't get it look good. I have search functions to do this in C and cannot find any?

A website used C# and `String.Format()` to achieve this, I wonder if this is possible to do in C ?

```
> [C#] Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
> Console.WriteLine("First Name | Last Name  |   Age");
> Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
> Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Bill",
> "Gates", 51)); Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} |
> {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114));
> Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny",
> "Depp", 44)); Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
```

OUTput be like:

```
 -------------------------------
 First Name | Last Name  |   Age
 -------------------------------
 Bill       | Gates      |    51
 Edna       | Parker     |   114
 Johnny     | Depp       |    44
 -------------------------------
```

In my own C I am trying to format one string and space or special character before and after such as:

```
--------------------------------
------This x costs y dollar-----
------This i costs j dollar-----
...
...
-------------------------------
```

The front would be %s the item name, and latter would be %d the cost.
My idea was like to print this in a loop, it loops `m`(total items) times define a `line` width of 30 total. Each loop find the length of the item name, use another loop to /10 of the cost to find it's len and add both of them together.
print ((`line`-`totalLen`)/2) in front, print the string and do the same after the string?
The small problem would be if the whole string is odd or even number.

Comment: Google for field width with `fprintf()` family.

Comment: "to output a menu in C but I can't get it look good." and "In my own C I am trying ..." --> post that code you are using.

Comment: This page may be useful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: @Idan@chux@Ghosh. Thanks I found the answer.