# How do I print a string between two pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I'm building a rocket for Elon Musk and the memory usage is very important to me.

I have text and a pointer to it `pText`. It's chilling in the heap.

Sometimes I need to analyse the string, its words. I don't store substrings in heap, instead I store two pointers start/end for represeting a substring of the text. But sometimes I need to print those substrings for debugging purposes. How do I do that?

I know that for a string to be printed I need two things

- a pointer to the begging
- null terminator at the end

Any ideas?

```
// Text
char *pText  = "We've sold the Earch!";

// Substring `sold`
char *pStart = &(pText + 6) // s
char *pEnd   = &(pStart + 3) // d

// Print that substring
printf("sold: %s", ???);
```

Comment: You can use `%.*s` specifier to pass the length of the string you wish to print

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256218/the-simplest-way-of-printing-a-portion-of-a-char-in-c

Comment: Two possible solutions come to my mind: 1. print the string character-by-character in a loop from start pointer to end pointer. 2. save the character after the end pointer, replace it with `'\0'`, print the string using normal string functions and restore the original character.

Comment: If it's just for debugging purposes, the performance doesn't usually play that much of a role. Why not print characters, like in : `for (int len = 0; len < 7; ++len) printf("%c", *(pStart + len));`

Comment: `&(pText + 6)` is wrong by the way, it should not use the pointer-to operator `&`.

Comment: You should be able to find these bugs easily by simply enabling all warnings and paying attention to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to *print* the sub-string, then use a precision argument for `printf`:

```
printf("sold: %.*s", (int) (pEnd - pStart) + 1, pStart);
```

---

If you need to use the sub-string in other ways then the simplest is probably to create a temporary string, copy into it, and then print that instead.

Perhaps something like this:

```
// Get the length of the sub-string
size_t length = pEnd - pStart + 1;

// Create an array for the sub-string, +1 for the null-terminator
char temp[length + 1];

// Copy the sub-string
memcpy(temp, pStart, length);

// Terminate it
temp[length] = '\0';
```

If you need to do this many times I recommend you create a generic function for this.

You might also need to dynamically allocate the string using `malloc` depending on use-case.

Comment: Alternatively instead of `memcpy and a '\0'` assignment, can use `snprintf()` ?

Comment: @WedaPashi That would of course work, but `snprintf` is probably a little more complex.